# How to revolve TinyIMCE error 'The version of TinyMCE could not be detected'?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files

I installed these modules: [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), [IMCE Wysiwyg bridge](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg), [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce).

Then downloaded the libraries from:

https://www.tinymce.com/download/ (developer edition, community doesn't even have a non minified imce.js file...)

Now the file structure is not the same as the instructions from Drupal Backend:

```
Extract the archive and copy its contents into a new folder in the      following location:
sites/all/libraries/tinymce

So the actual library can be found at:
sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
```

So I deducted I had to change folder structure from:

```
sites/all/libraries/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js
```

To:

```
sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
```

But still not working, I get this error:

```
TinyMCE (Download)  Not installed.
The version of TinyMCE could not be detected.
```

Comment: I think you should check the version of tinymce library you are you using. Please check the documentation of right version.

Comment: You may try using some older verion, or try version 3.5 or 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use the last dev version of Wysiwyg, you can read more about this [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/711230).

And you need read the [Supported Editors Matrix](https://www.drupal.org/node/596966).

I download the [3.5.11](http://download.moxiecode.com/tinymce/tinymce_3.5.11_dev.zip) version of TinyMCE from [here](http://archive.tinymce.com/download/older.php) and copy the tinymce folder to `YOUR_SITE/sites/all/libraries/` so inside this folder you must have this:

[image]

So I have installed:

[Wysiwyg 7.x-2.x-dev](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/wysiwyg-7.x-2.x-dev.zip)
[TinyMCE 3.5.11](http://download.moxiecode.com/tinymce/tinymce_3.5.11_dev.zip)

And it works ;-)

Comment: Ok, this worked finally...what a pain...I really like that "supported editors matrix" page at https://www.drupal.org/node/596966  that would have saved me hours...are there any pages like that that cover ALL compatibility issues for drupal modules and libraries?

Comment: @BrunoVincent I don't know about other pages, and good luck with your project